# Constant element in Ada object?

Tags: ada

In Java or C#, you would often have class members that are `final` or `readonly` - they are set once and then never touched again. They can hold different values for different instances of the class.

Is there something similar in Ada? I've tried to create something similar in Ada thusly:

```
package MyPackage is

   type MyObject is limited new OtherPackage.Object with private;

....

private

   type MyObject (...) is limited new OtherPackage.Object with
      record
         M_MyField : Integer := 10;
         M_MyConstantFactory : constant Factory.Object'Class := new Factory.Object;
      end record;

end MyPackage;
```

This fails on the declaration of `M_MyConstantFactory` saying `constant components are not permitted`. Is there a way around this? A colleague suggested declaring it somewhere else in the package, but that would mean a single `M_MyConstantFactory` shared across all instances, which is not what I want.

Do I need to just accept that it is possible to modify the value once set and manually guard against that happening?

Comment: The answers so far are good workarounds. But I think the ultimate answer based on my research in the last week is that it can't be done in Ada. I just have to use one of the workarounds mentioned in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer the question, it would probably be helpful to distinguish between Ada and Java/C#'s modeling of objects. In Java, everything is an object, and so all constants have to be `final` -- in Ada things are a bit different, Ada's object-system ("tagged types" in Ada parlance) is built upon two items: records and type-derivation. This means that, when teaching OOP, we could arrive gradually introducing first type-derivation (eg `Type Degree is new Integer;`), then records (ie encapsulation), then `private`-types (ie information-hiding), and finally unifying everything together with tagged-types... all of which I'll assume you are cognizant of.

In Ada, a `constant` is just that: some object that can be read but [generally] not written to. (Things can get funny with eg memory-mapped IO.) So we could say:

```
Package Ex1 is
  Type Stub1 is private; -- Some type, with almost nothing public.
  C1 : Constant Stub1;   -- A constant of that type.
Private
  Type Stub1 is tagged record
    Data_1 : Integer;
    Data_2 : Float;
  end;

  -- And now we can tell the compiler what C1 _is_.
  C1: Constant Stub1 := (Data_1 => 3, Data_2 => 1.2);
End Ex1;
```

That's how we'd make a constant for a tagged type while keeping its implementation details hidden; though, admittedly, we could have exposed everything and gotten rid of the entire `private` section.

Now we get to an interesting feature of records [and tagged types] called discriminants -- these are kind of like constants, and kind of like generic-types in other languages. With discriminants we could make a message-type that varies in size according to the message-length:

```
Package Ex2 is
  Type Message(Length : Natural) is private; -- A message.
  Function Create( Text : String ) return Message;
Private
  Type Message(Length : Natural) is record
    Data : String(1..Length) := (Others => ' '); -- Defaults to space-filled string.
  end;

  Function Create( Text : String ) return Message is
  ( Data => Text, Length => Text'Length );
End Ex2;
```

Now, in this case, when you do an assignment like `X : Message := Create("Steve");` the variavle's type [unconstrained, in this example, becomes constrained in this case to `Message(5)` (because "Steve" is 5 characters) and so trying to re-assign with a different-sized message-string wouldn't work. (So, while you couldn't say `X:= Create("Why")` you *can* say `X:= Create("Hello")` because the discriminant [`Length`] here is 5.) -- So, in that manner discriminants can act like constant fields in some cases.

The `limited` keyword means that the type doesn't have an assignment [but does have initialization], so you *could* make the entire type behave as a constant; this is different than having the one component be `constant` though, certainly not as subtle as the distinction between `T` and `T'Class` (`T'Class` is the Type `T` and all types derived therefrom, where as `T` is *only* that type.)

Answer (score 7):

No.  Not quite.

If your component is of a discrete type or an access type, you can make it a discriminant, and thus make it immutable.

```ada
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Immutable_Components is

   type Instance (Immutable : Positive) is null record;

   A : Instance := (Immutable => 1);

begin
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (A.Immutable);

   --  A.Immutable := 2; --  assignment to discriminant not allowed:
end Immutable_Components;
```

Comment: I wouldn't have put all the information hiding in the example code; the `Immutable` discriminant also cannot be changed when the type is public.

Comment: Can this sort of approach allow for settable values as well? The thing I'm finding tricky is having both readonly and non-readonly in the same record.

Comment: Sort of, but I would suggest that you use the method you used in your question for the mutable values, and combine that with discriminants.

Comment: Notice that it is possible to make the discriminants private, if you don't want to give users of the type direct access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have the general solution (for cases when it can't be a discriminant) already. The type is limited private. Clients of the package can only modify it through the operations the pkg provides. As long as the operations don't modify the field in question, you have what you want (unless I misunderstood and the question is how to prevent yourself from modifying the field in the pkg body).